# JSTL if does not work

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have some problems using JSTL tags. I added dependecies on pom.xml
Here is the code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Course</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>


<body>

    <c:out value="AAA"></c:out>

    <c:set var="age" value="26" />

    <c:if test="${age >= 18}">
        <c:out value="You are eligible for voting!" />
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${age < 18}">
        <c:out value="You are not eligible for voting!" />
    </c:if>

</body>

</html>
```

c:out tag works.
c:if tag does not work, although IDE does not give any errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This prints _You are eligible for voting!_ in my browser.

Comment: since this is a copy paste of https://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jstl-cif-core-tag/ , i'm going to say the JSP is right.  you have issues elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<c:if test="${age >= '18'}">
    <c:out value="You are eligible for voting!" />
</c:if>
```

Comment: Why is this going to work, while the posted code apparently is not working?